# ChartJs - width scale of chart area and label area

Tags: chart.js

I created a donut chart but its width of data area and label area is not what I intended.

How can I increase the width of data(chart) area - i.e. 60% and decrease the width of label area proportionately?

image link as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsoT3.png

```
<div style="text-align: center;" class='sector-exposure'>
      <canvas
        baseChart
        [data]="sectorChartData"
        [labels]="sectorChartLabels"
        [chartType]="exposureChartType"
        [options]="exposureChartOptions"
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
```

```
public exposureChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    legend: {
      position: right,
      labels: {
        fontColor: '#d5d6d6',
        fontSize: this.isMobileWidth ? 10 : 16,
      },
    },
  };


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsoT3.png
```

Answer (score -1):

May be following settings will work for you. Set `responsive` to `true` and `maintainAspectRatio` to `false` in the chart options and set style as like as max-height: 300px (more or less); width: auto; in canvas.

```
...
var config = {
  type: 'doughnutLabels',
  data: {
    ...
  },
  options: {    
    ...    
    responsive: true, //IMPORTANT        
    maintainAspectRatio: false, //IMPORTANT
    ...
    legend: {
      ...
      position: 'right',
      ...
      labels: {   
        ...  
        fontColor: '#d5d6d6',      
        fontSize: this.isMobileWidth ? 10 : 16,
        ...
      }
    },
    animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true
    }        
  }
};
...
```

Comment: Thanks...whatever I do, the donut chart doesn't seem natural...Rather, I just want to display labels only and hide the donut chart. Is it possible?